# How to check user's platform and run the corresponding command in Python script using subprocess?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, subprocess

I need to execute a command that varies based on the user's platform. I currently have it set up this way in a Python script:

```
import platform
user_sys = platform.system()
if user_sys == 'Linux' or 'Darwin':
    cmd = "cat file1 file2..."
elif user_sys == 'Windows':
    cmd = "type file1 file2..."
subprocess.run(split(cmd))  # run on command line
```

Questions

1. Is there a better way of executing based on the user's platform?
2. Would it be more advisable/conventional to make two separate programs for the operating systems rather than trying to combine it all in one script?

Answer (score 0):

no their isn't any better way to extract this info, their is no need multi-pal scripts.

this is what i suggest you can improve upon

```
from sys import platform as _platform

if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
    # linux
elif _platform == "darwin":
    # MAC OS X
elif _platform == "win32":
    # Windows
elif _platform == "win64":
    # Windows 64-bit
```